# java jaxb eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, validation

I have a few JAXB projects in my eclipse, which work fine. But sometimes when im working on projects in eclipse (not on the JAXB projects) an error pops up and says that one of my JAXB have and validation error - nullpointer exception. Is there an validation in eclipse that runs in the background? Why is eclipse validating projects im not currently work on?

The error message: 
"Problem occurred

Validating project X has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during "Validating project X"
java.lang.nullpointerexception"

This error messages pops up even when im working on project y that has no relation to project x.
It pops up when im saving a class.

Comment: Showing us the error message might help.

Comment: Actually, i don't really get the problem.... You have a workspace with some projects that contain JAXB bound Classes. And when you run another project you get some NullPointerExceptions?! ... Are they even related to the JAXB classes?

Comment: not only when i run other projects. The error message just pops now and then.. The project im working on has not relation to JAXB class. Im working on JSF projects. The error message that pops up says that there is a validation problem in a specific JAXB project, but it is not always the same JAXB project the error message refere to. Under details in the error message it says that there is an nullpointer in the JAXB project.

Comment: look at the question again - i have written the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your entire workspace is being built instead of one project, or some of the projects are built because the one you're working on depends on them. Whether or not that's the case depends on your build process. (standard, Ant, Maven... ?)

The null pointer exception does make it sound more like it's an actual bug, however.

What you could do is open menu Window, choose Preferences and select the Validation page. Check what's enabled there and disable anything you suspect might cause this. It is possible to do this for specific projects, so it might be best to do so directly on the JAXB ones.

Comment: The validation is disabled on all of the projects.Im using eclipse indigo. As said in the question, the error message often pops up when i save a class.

Comment: @uthen Definitely looks like a bug in Eclipse. See if you can find a publicly accessible issue tracker and search in it. If the issue wasn't reported yet, consider filing a bug report. I'm still on Eclipse Helios and don't have the JAXB-bound project type in that, so I haven't encountered it myself. Besides, I primarily use NetBeans.